# Position searchbox beside textarea keywords using jquery css

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, css-position

Here i have a fiddle  [***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/evaF7/).
What i wanted was to position the `#searchbox` accordingly beside the entered keyword over textarea. But how do i get position of entered keyword in textarea and position the `#searchbox`?

Comment: Does the `#searchbox` go inside the `textarea` next to the keyword or outside the `textarea` but the `top` position changing depending on the number of keyword lines?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: inside `textarea` next to keyword! @ICanHasKittenz

Comment: i want to get the`#searchbox` beside the keyword i entered just now! @StenPelzer

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have got at the moment.
I have been trying to make it work for an hour now, but i really have to go back to my own work now.
[This is what i have got so far](http://jsfiddle.net/evaF7/1/)

Maybe you , or somebody who wants to, can work with it and maybe it works out!

I would like to hear what you have done, when you finally made it happen!

```
Good luck!
```

Comment: this not i wanted it only moves left! i want `#searchbox` to appeaer beside the `caret` of my textarea

Comment: i don't understand what you're saying, sorry. Can you maybe give me an example or image where you can see it?

Comment: Updated my fiddle, i haven't got anymore time again now, but when i have time i will try and see if i can help you out. You can work on it yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/evaF7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tried:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n2v7M/)**

First, instead of `textarea`, use `div` with `contenteditable` attribute, with this we can type text inside `div` and also place elements.

Next, the jQuery:

```
var lines = 1;
var first_line = true;


//Credits to digitalzoomstudio at http://digitalzoomstudio.net/2013/06/19/calculate-text-width-with-jquery/
//This function finds the exact width of the text entered
jQuery.fn.textWidth = function () {
    var _t = jQuery(this);
    var html_org = _t.html();
    if (_t[0].nodeName == 'INPUT') {
        html_org = _t.val();
    }
    var html_calcS = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    jQuery('body').append(html_calcS);
    var _lastspan = jQuery('span').last();
    _lastspan.css({
        'font-size': _t.css('font-size'),
        'font-family': _t.css('font-family')
    })
    var width = _lastspan.width() + 5;
    _lastspan.remove();
    return width;
};

$("#textarea").one("keyup", function () {
    //the searchbox should show only the first time the key is pressed
    $('#searchbox').show();
});
$('#textarea').keyup(function (e) {

    if(first_letter = true){
      $('#searchbox').show();
    }
    if (first_line) {
        //Credits to Viral Patel for this bit of code at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/
       //This one retrieves the text instead a div after removing 
       //all its child elements
        var content = $(this).clone() //clone the element
            .children() //select all the children
            .remove() //remove all the children
            .end() //again go back to selected element
            .text();
        $('#searchbox').css('top', 20);
    } else {
        var content = $('div', this).eq(-2).clone() //clone the element
            .children() //select all the children
            .remove() //remove all the children
            .end() //again go back to selected element
            .text();

    }
    lastLine = "<span>" + content + "</span>";
    pos = $(lastLine).textWidth();
    $('#searchbox').css('top', lines * 20);
    $('#searchbox').html(content);

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        first_line = false;
        lines = lines + 1;
        $('#searchbox').css('left', 20);
        $('#searchbox').html('');
        $('#searchbox').hide();
        first_letter = true;
    } else {
        $('#searchbox').css('left', pos + 10);
        first_letter = false;
    }

});
```

Comment: This has  a lot of abug!

Comment: @HackerManiac What kind of bug?

Comment: type  very fast on the div. or copy paste stuff then the `#searchbox` will be illpositioned

Comment: @HackerManiac So do you want the continuous text to flow above the container and keep going on till the enter key is pressed, just like the way in Google+?

Comment: yes kinda! @ICanHasKittenz in google+ its only when u press a `#` but i want it everytime....any solution will work!